# What’s the meaning of “Well... dang” in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

So I read a post today about “say no more” memes from barbers. One of the meme is like this:

[image: The meme]

Then one of the comment said: “Well... dang.”

I frequently see this statement, but I can’t quite grasp what this actually express in literal. “Dang” feels like a word with thousands of meaning depends on the context. So here I present the context. If the commenter is asked to elaborate what he’s trying to express with his “well... dang.” what he’s actually say? Did he praise the meme’s cleverness? Did he sympathize with the person in the picture? Did he mock at the person in the picture? Did he mock at the barber’s job? Or something else? Thanks.

Comment: You might as well keep guessing, since there's no real way to know.  It could be saying, *Indeed, there is a likeness!*

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo oh I see. So I already understand the word correctly, which is meant to not have a precise meaning. Thanks!